# Can't write to writable folder /tmp/ on S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I've tried writing a file to writable /tmp/ folder inside my bucket with a lamda function but got AccessDenied error. This is weird since I can do it by calling the lambda function locally. Below is the code for the lambda function:

```
import json
import boto3
import os

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    print(event)
    session = boto3.Session(profile_name=os.environ.get("MY_PROFILE", None))
    
    client = session.client("s3")
    os.chdir('/tmp')
    with open('test.txt', "w") as f:
        f.write("testing")
    client.upload_file('test.txt', 'my-bucket', 'tmp/test.txt')
```

and here is the error log:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Failed to upload test.txt to my-bucket/tmp/test.txt: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied",
  "errorType": "S3UploadFailedError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 14, in lambda_handler\n    client.upload_file('test.txt', 'gp-model-bucket', 'tmp/test.txt')\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/boto3/s3/inject.py\", line 131, in upload_file\n    extra_args=ExtraArgs, callback=Callback)\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/boto3/s3/transfer.py\", line 287, in upload_file\n    filename, '/'.join([bucket, key]), e))\n"
  ]
}
```

Can someone help me out please?

Comment: When you run the lambda function locally, it is running under your role. That means that it has your permissions (or the permissions of the profile you give it or it can find - from ~/.aws or environment variables.) When you run it in AWS, it runs under its own execution role - see the answer by @Marcin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add S3 write permissions into your [AWS Lambda execution role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-intro-execution-role.html). You can add the following IAM policy to your role:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Other permissions may be required, e.g. KMS permissions if your bucket uses default KMS encryption.

Comment: I've added PutObject permission for IAM policy but the issue remained, here is the updated policy:

`
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::myl-bucket/*"
        }
    ]
} `

The error is "OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'test.txt' "

Comment: @AnNguyen This is new issue and new error message. You have to write to `/tmp/text.txt`.  Only /tmp is writable.